# Formatting results by groups based on conditions?

Tags: php, mysql

I have data from two different tables that I join together and run a query against.

What I am trying to achieve is that my results will group based on the order number, and possibly one other condition - if it works out.

I am trying to generate price quotes based on damaged items that we receive back in stock.

One quote can hold multiple work record ids so long as that the order numbers match up and those order numbers were all entered on the same day.  The one caveat being if one of those work records happens to have an item that we have to send out to the manufacturer to get an estimate on (which is a flag in the main database table that I'm bringing in.

For now though, I would like to take the data I'm getting back and display it on the screen as a preview  of what the quotes will contain prior to the system sending them out.

The end result that I am looking for can be found in this image I've mocked up:

[image: Mockup of wanted end result]

Here is my query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT workRecord_details.orderNumber, workRecord_main.mfrEstimate, workRecord_main.id, workRecord_main.createdDate, workRecord_main.nameid, workRecord_details.dateEntered
                        FROM workRecord_main
                        INNER JOIN workRecord_details ON workRecord_main.id = workRecord_details.workRecordId
                        WHERE workRecord_main.billable = '1' AND workRecord_main.STATUS = '2' AND workRecord_details.dateEntered LIKE '2013-08-14%' ORDER BY workRecord_details.orderNumber, workRecord_main.mfrEstimate, workRecord_main.id"
                    ) or die("Can't execute: " . mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($getWR) > 0){
$i = 0;
while($wrData = mysql_fetch_array($getWR))
    {
        $color_A = 'class="alt2"'; 
        $color_B = 'class="alt1"';

        $row_color = ($i % 2) ? $color_A : $color_B;        

        echo '<table width = "100%" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">
                <tr>
                    <td class = "colheader">Work Record #</td>
                    <td class = "colheader">Company</td>
                    <td class = "colheader">Order #</td>
                    <td class = "colheader">Description</td>
                </tr>';

        echo '<tr>
                <td width= "100px" ' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['id'] . '</td>
                <td width = "150px"' . $row_color . '>' . companyNameByNameID($wrData['nameid']) . '('.getKdaccount($wrData['nameid']).')</td>
                <td width = "100px"' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['orderNumber'] . '</td>
                <td width = "600px"' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['partNo'] . '</td>
            </tr>';

        echo '</table><br /><br />';


        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements as mysql_ functions have been deprecated.

Comment: Also could you use the MySQL GROUP BY function, http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx

Comment: If you want to create a 'mock up', consider SQLFIDDLE.

Comment: I definitely should move to PDF with prepared statements, but we are running PHP 5.2 and will not be able to upgrade for a long time, as this is a corporate intranet which would all have to be re-written in order to upgrade.  Hopefully one day that'll happen.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1de84/6)

Comment: @Dan If you rally planning to change of DB API, in the the "main code" you should probably access the DB through an abstraction layer instead of spreading API call all around...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, I'm sorry, but I don't follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create tables based off the order number, or send to mfr flag, you need to track the last used order number and/or flag. Try something like this -

```
$i = 0;
$current_orderNumber = ''; //variable to track current orderNumber
$color_A = 'class="alt2"'; 
$color_B = 'class="alt1"';
while($wrData = mysql_fetch_array($getWR))
{
     // Start a new table for each orderNumber or if send to mfr is set
 if($wrData['orderNumber'] != $current_orderNumber || isset(YOUR_SEND_TO_MFR_FLAG)){
        if($i!=0){  // if not the first table, close the last table
        echo '</table><br /><br />';
    }
            // start a new table
    echo '<table width = "100%" cellspacing = "0" cellpadding = "0" border = "0">
            <tr>
                <td class = "colheader">Work Record #</td>
                <td class = "colheader">Company</td>
                <td class = "colheader">Order #</td>
                <td class = "colheader">Description</td>
            </tr>';
 $i=0; //reset the row # for the new table
 }
    $current_orderNumber = $wrData['orderNumber']; // set current orderNumber to this orderNumber

    $row_color = ($i % 2) ? $color_A : $color_B;        

    echo '<tr>
            <td width= "100px" ' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['id'] . '</td>
            <td width = "150px"' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['nameid'] .'</td>
            <td width = "100px"' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['orderNumber'] . '</td>
            <td width = "600px"' . $row_color . '>' . $wrData['partNo'] . '</td>
        </tr>';

    $i++;
}
echo '</table><br /><br />'; // close the last table.
```

phpFiddle example -  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7kx-qgw